# Factory girl not making attributes correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, factory-bot

I am writing a controller_spec_test using Rspec on a model called `Form`. And I use FactoryGirl to generate models. When I run individual tests in `form_controller_spec`, they all pass. However, when I run the whole file, I see all test are failing and the error msg is `ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
       Validation failed: Form type can't be blank`.

Here is my `forms.rb` Factorygirl file,
FactoryGirl.define do

```
  factory :form do
    association :user
        sequence :form_type do |n|
            Form.form_types.values[n]
        end

  end
end
```

Here is my form.rb model file:

```
class Form < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, required: true

    enum form_types: { :a => "Form A", :b => "Form B", :c => "Form C", :d => "Form D"}

  validates :form_type, presence: true
  validates :form_type, uniqueness: {scope: :user_id}

end
```

Here is my forms_controller_spec.rb file:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe FormsController, type: :controller do

  login_user

    let(:form) {
        FactoryGirl.create(:form, user: @current_user)
    }

    let(:forms) {
        FactoryGirl.create_list(:form , 3, user: @current_user)

    }

    let(:form_attributes) {
        FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:form, user: @current_user)
    }

    describe "GET #index" do
        before do
            @forms = forms
        end

        it "loads all of the forms into @forms" do
            get :index
            expect(assigns(:forms)).to match_array(@forms)
        end
    end

end
```

I do not get that individual tests are passing but the tests are failing when I run the whole file. And I also do not know why `form_type` is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Your :form_attributes method is missing an appropriate value for :form_type

```
let(:form_attributes) {
    FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:form, "Form C", user: @current_user)
}
```

Although you also can't seem to make up your mind whether you want a string or an integer, as in the call above to `let(:forms)` you've passed in the integer 3. That's an inconsistency that probably needs to be fixed one way or the other.

Comment: Wait, I'm confused. I put integer 3 to make three `form` models. I thought that was the syntax. And the reason I did not pass attribute (`form_type`) is because I thought `sequence` in `factory :form do` block is automatically generating the attribute even if I do not set it explictily like you dud,

Comment: I honestly have never used "sequence" so you're probably right. Nevertheless, nowhere are you giving a value for form_type like "Form A" or "Form C", which is obviously what you're expecting, so I think that's what you should be looking at changing since of course it's not being set.